# Как из строки вытащить число?

Tags: javascript, html, css

пример 11.11.1999

получить 11111999

вместо точек может быть что угодно

Comment: в отрыве от задачи - никак....так не ясно что это за строка и сколько чисел там есть и надо ли им быть всем одним числом или всё это должны быть разные числа и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать используя регулярное выражение:

```
let str = '+7(123)456-78-90';

console.log(str.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
```

Оно удаляет все кроме цифр

Comment: `/\D/g` - так чуть проще.